# Не срабатывает strpos

Tags: php, строки

Имеется строка:

```
Ссылка на описание и полную версию
```

Нужно проверить переменную на наличие такой строки.

```
$find = "Ссылка на описание и полную версию";
    if(strpos($productArr[$i]["description"],$find)){
        $description = "";
    }
    else{
    $description = $productArr[$i]["description"];
}
```

Вот вся строка, которую я получаю:

```
Ссылка на описание и полную версию :https://crispy.com.ua/ottie/first-swing-recovery-essence-ottie
```

Не могу понять почему не находит вхождение этой подстроки

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Не могу понять почему не находит вхождение этой подстроки*

Вероятно потому, что strpos() возвращает **позицию** первого вхождения строки. Если это `0`, то в скобках оператора `if ()` он будет преобразован в `false`, и выполнится блок кода `else`. Используйте оператор `===` для проверки значения, возвращаемого этой функцией:

```
$i = 0;
$productArr[0]["description"] = "Ссылка на описание и полную версию :https://crispy.com.ua/ottie/first-swing-recovery-essence-ottie";

$find = "Ссылка на описание и полную версию";

if (strpos($productArr[$i]["description"], $find) !== false) {
    $description = $productArr[$i]["description"];
} else {
    $description = "";
}

echo $description;
```

---

Для работы с многобайтовыми кодировками используйте [mb_strpos()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-strpos.php).